# How to handle asynchronous query to a redis server using one connection?

Tags: ios, macos, swift, redis, jedis

I'm now developing a redis client for swift. I tried to use asynchronous callback delegate to handle to result sent from the redis server using:

```
func stream(aStream: NSStream, handleEvent eventCode: NSStreamEvent)
```

But every time I will open a new connection with the server and after a command is executed, the connection will be closed which is not efficient. 
I looked up how Jedis implement this and figured out Jedis is using its inputstream's 'read' function which is a synchronous call - it will block the process until the last command's result is received. My question is, how can I do this using Apple's NSStream? 
One idea is to poll request after sending a command, but is there a more graceful way to do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?